# Integrate WebRTC in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, webrtc

There don't seem to be any APIs / examples of how to **integrate WebRTC in Xamarin**. There is a third party API (IceLink) by a company named Frozen Mountain Software but one requires a paid license to use it.

Any clue as to how to do this ?

Comment: are you able to integrate WebRTC ? I am new to this concept. In my requirement, i need to have a discussion chat  feature on a tabbed page. I wonder whether WebRTC was helpful to you .. please let us know

Comment: @goofyui : No, I didn't bother, seems a bit complicated, with absolutely no examples to follow, i'd rather not get into it with Xamarin. Alternatively, i suggest that you either use React Native as there is a ready made example on using WebRTC in it or use a library such as Twilio for WebRTC in which you would have to use the Native SDKs for Android and iOS to perform some sort of binding with Xamarin, which again seems a bit complex with no examples available. As far as your requirement of having a chat feature you could use Firebase (the real time database) or SignalR.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use [WebRTC native](https://webrtc.org/native-code/development/) libraries for Xamarin. If you are good with using precompiled libraries then you may find it over web. However I prefer to compile webrtc native for each target platform. Google has documented steps very well, but it usually take time.

Once you have libraries ready for your platform then you can use it with xamarin. Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Are there any examples of this available ?

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov No change as per my knowledge. You will have to use either pre-compiled libraries from web Or compile from webrtc source code.